# How Can I Center the Logo in the Navigation Menu?

Tags: php, css, html

I'd like to center the logo in the navigation menu. I understand how to do it if it were not PHP based. Does anyone have any insight on this? You can view the test site [here](http://s513195336.onlinehome.us/) Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no way to center the logo using PHP. Thats what CSS is for so this question should be asked on another site.

Answer (score 1):

As this is a premium theme, I would recommend going back to the original developer for a improvement request.

You might find they are already implementing this or might be interested in your feedback and initiate the changes.

http://themeforest.net/item/medicenter-responsive-medical-health-template/4000598

Comment: Thanks. I am currently seeking support from the developer, but I'd like to take action on this asap. If possible.

Answer (score -1):

look at your style.css 
line 352 and add this:

.header_left {
    float: none;
    margin: auto;
    width: 320px;

Comment: Thank you, this does work for centering the logo, but I want to center it within the navigation menu. Like perhaps even as a list item.

Comment: Please make a screenshot and align the elements the way you want them to be. This will help me understanding it.